# How to get Oracle node in release 1.0

Tags: corda

Up to Milestone 14, I was used to get the Oracle node using:

```
val nodes = serviceHub.networkMapCache.getNodesWithService(*ServiceType*)
```

Now in release 1.0, according to the oracle-example, the Oracle Node lookup has to be made by legal name, is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's correct. You'd use something like:

`networkMapCache.getNodeByLegalName(oracleName)?.legalIdentities?.first() ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("Requested oracle $oracleName not found on network.")`

We will be re-introducing service identities in some form in the future.